# how do i compile all variables within one codeblock?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, mean, boxplot

i want to collect data from a boxplot that i created but i am not able to compile all of them in one codeblock. I have to do each of them in separate blocks.

```
import numpy as np

np.mean(product_ratings["Rating"])
np.min(product_ratings["Rating"])
np.max(product_ratings["Rating"])
product_ratings.quantile([0.25,0.5,0.75])
```

so i tried to put these in one block but only an answer to the last code comes up to the screen. How can i keep all answers in one codeblock?

Comment: Assign them to variables and then `print` them? Better yet would be to collect them in a function that outputs a dictionary or named tuple.

Comment: omg yes. this is just embarassing. thanks